# Docker login get failed with nexus repository

Tags: docker, authentication, nexus, nexus3

We use the nexus repository manager (oss 3.22.1.-02 ) and for the first time, we are trying to setup a Docker repository with nexus. When we trying to execute docker login we are getting this error message.

```
Error:
error logging  in to v2 end point trying next end point <url> failed with status 404 Not found
```

How we can fix this issue. we use Docker (18.09) version with this test

Comment: with what url are u accessing the docker registry?

Comment: we are using nexus url to access docker repos

Comment: are you using the docker registry port that you defined in nexus?

Answer (score 0):

By configuring the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file I was able to resolve this issue.

```js
{ 
 "insecure-registries": [<nexus hostname>:<port>],

 "disable-legacy-registry": true  
}
```

Comment: The insecure registry setting wouldn't cause a 404 on the v2 api call. You'd see a different error that's solved by this setting.